# is using git fetch upstream better or can I just clone the parent (someone else's) repo separatly?

Tags: git, github

I forked a git hub project on which I have to work on, what advantages will git hub fetch upstream provide because I can keep track on that project by updating it in separated folder, I feel its the easier way to do that!

Comment: It will depend on your [project's] workflow style. Is this fork simply to give you a place for your holding your personal development attempts as you refine them (i.e. act as an archive), later pushing your clean code to the upstream? Or something else e.g. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows or http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Are you simply 'lurking' (that is only following the upstream) or do you hope to do some local development (with features and branches) that may later/eventually be contributed upstream?

Comment: So you would hope that 'they' will want to pull your contribution. Using a fork allows you to prepare publicly a nice branch (commit series), while the fork can also act as your backup and hold copies of all your WIP (work in progress) branches. As a personal fork, folk don't expect all the branches to be polished - see how many forks have already been made of the repo you are interested in and have a look at their WIP to see a pattern (or anti-pattern;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collating my previous answers:

You would generally only clone a repo if you were a friend of the repo owner or had a suitable working relationship, (or they positively encourage it) so that when you push back a new branch of your work it would not cause any upset. This can avoid the branch bloat problem.

You would tend to fork a repo when you are interested in the work and want to try something out without having to get 'permission' first, which is one of the benefits of a DVCS system. The fork process also (automatically) provides you with a place of archive for your local work on the github server.

It will depend on your [project's] workflow style e.g. [git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) or [nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Using a fork allows you to prepare publicly a nice branch (commit series), and hold copies of all your WIP (work in progress) branches. As a personal fork, folk don't expect all the branches to be polished - see how many forks have already been made of the repo you are interested in and have a look at their WIP to see a pattern (or anti-pattern;-)

Comment: Just seen https://gist.github.com/2715053 linked from a Code Project news item http://blog.jayfields.com/2012/05/how-i-open-source.html which summarises the personal vs project activities.